# How to decompress zlib NSData

Tags: ios, zlib

I hve some compressed Zlib NSData that I would like to unzip or 'inflate' etc but I am getting an error on the following code

```
NSData* originalData = [compressedData zlibInflate];
```

This bit of code gives me this error

```
No visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'zlibInflate'
```

I have no idea how to fix it, I have looked around but cannot find anything... Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**FILES:**

http://blakeseely.com/svn/public/SniperKit/trunk/Additions/NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.h

http://blakeseely.com/svn/public/SniperKit/trunk/Additions/NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.m

These are the two files you need to add to your project and reference where you need to use them.

Comment: Do you actually have the zlibInflate software in your app?

Comment: oh crap.. I imported libz.dylib framework.. is that the same thing??? I have a feeling its not.

Comment: I just checked I dont think it is the same thing.. where can I download the zlib.h/.m

Comment: Where did you read to use this function?  You are using an objective-c function, but libz is a C-library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1925554/748343

Comment: The category that provides this function is linked in that answer....download it...use it...like I said in my answer.

Comment: OMG, never saw the link on the **Here** word..... in that page however I cannot find a download button for that code... still looking but cannot see.

Comment: Cocoadev is hideous in my opinion (looks like it was made a decade ago)...you have to copy and paste the function you need directly from the wiki (to which I say...WTF...seriously?!)

Comment: lol, yea I am looking at it scratching my head.. there is formatting and everything in that page that will mess everything up so I kept looking for some type of download link.... but nothing.. I have searched for other alternatives but cannot find much.

Comment: Oh man had a lucky find
http://blakeseely.com/svn/public/SniperKit/trunk/Additions/NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.h
and
http://blakeseely.com/svn/public/SniperKit/trunk/Additions/NSData+CocoaDevUsersAdditions.m

Comment: I use Objective-Zip by the way...It is a fine alternative

Comment: hrmm, looks interesting.. how do you use it with NSData? seems like its used for files specifically but I have only just quickly read the readme file from their git depository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the header that declares the function `zLibInflate`...It is probably something like `NSData+zlib.h`